# Is Tomcat's performance reduced by introducing more filters?

Tags: performance, tomcat, servlet-filters

Is the performance of tomcat is reduced if we implement more filters in the web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. If you ask the container to do more work, it will get slower.

I can't give you a more specific answer until you give us a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont have specific scenario. Just asked for my knowledge.